# PHP - Laravel 8 динамическое пространство имён use

Tags: php, laravel, ооп

Добрый день ищу элегантный метод с передачей пространства имен, пример:

```
use App\Services\SuppliersApiParsers\parserName;// Планирую в этой папке создать кучу парсеров, для каждого свой файл, т.е parserName1, parserName2

class SuppliersPrice implements SuppliersPriceInterfaces
{
//..
  private function getSuppliers($store_supplier)
    {
$parser= SuppliersApiStoreSet::where('store_supplier', $store_supplier)   
                    ->first();
$parserFile = $parser->file;
       
        echo parserName::showBasicFunction();
//Но хочу: $parserFile::showSupplierBrandList();

    }
}
```

Все парсеры будут иметь на выходе типизированные данные, но магия их получения будет скрыта в каждом файле. Имена этих файлов буду дергать из БД, в зависимости от потребности запроса.

Comment: я что-то непонял, в чем вопрос собственно состоит. неймспейс известен, имя классов тоже. в чем загвоздка?

Comment: Немспейс - не зивестен, его имя планирую братьь из базы. В том то и дело, функцию я могу определить, а класс нет:                        $nameFun = 'getSuppliers';
                        echo self::$nameFun($store_supplier);

Comment: один черт не понимаю, в чем загвоздка. Можно вписать в строку имя класса с неймспейсом и создать из нее экземпляр. типа `$className = "\\app\\parsers\MyAwesomeParser"; $p = new $className`. Это не решает вашу задачу? В приведенном фрагменте кода, не явно вообще о чем речь идет.

Comment: Спасибо и правда - решил проблемму, огромное спасибо!   $suppliersClass = 'App\Services\SuppliersApiParsers\parser';
        $p = new $suppliersClass;
        $p::showFunction();